# Extracting NDVI over time using Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, ndvi

I am trying to extract NDVI data for provinces in Cambodia over time. The following codes work for a specific year (2002).

Can someone show me a better way to collect the data over time automatically on GEE?

```
var collection = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LE07/C01/T1_32DAY_NDVI')
.filterDate('2002-01-01', '2002-12-31').select('NDVI');

var mean = collection.reduce(ee.Reducer.mean());

var meanDictionary = mean.reduceRegions({
  collection: Cambodia,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  scale: 30,
});

Export.table.toDrive(meanDictionary,"NDVI","NDVI","NDVI_Cambodia");
```

Answer (score 4):

You will need to define a list of years you are interested in, and map over that list to get a mean NDVI image for every year. Then use `reduceRegion` on every image to obtain the mean NDVI value in the geometry. Export the resulting image collection as a table.

```
// Load collection and geometry
var Cambodia = geometry;
var collection = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LE07/C01/T1_32DAY_NDVI').select('NDVI');

// Declare years of interest
var years = ee.List.sequence(2000, 2010);

// Map a function to select data within the year and apply mean reducer
var byYear = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(
    years.map(function(y) {
      var image = collection.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(y, y, 'year'))
              .mean();
        // get the mean value for each year
      var meanDictionary = image.reduceRegion({ // use reduce region for single geometry
        geometry: Cambodia,
        reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
        scale: 30,
      });
      //set data to image
      return image.set(meanDictionary)
          // add time information to image
          .set('year', y,'system:time_start', ee.Date.fromYMD(y,1,1).millis())
    })
  );

// to test code printing, increase the scale or decrease size goemetry
// print(byYear)

// export the image collection as a table (CSV)
Export.table.toDrive(byYear,"NDVI","NDVI","NDVI_Cambodia");
```

[link code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/ef429d1d5115844db2ae8d56262a58fc)

-- EDIT --

user requested the code for featurecollections:

```
// Map a function to select data within the year and apply mean reducer
var byYear = ee.FeatureCollection(years.map(function(y) {
      var image = collection.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(y, y, 'year'))
              .mean();
        // get the mean value for each year
      var newFC = image.reduceRegions({ 
                              // use reduceRegion for single geometry
                              // use reduceRegions for multiple features
        collection: Cambodia,
        reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
        scale: 30,
        tileScale : 1, // increase tileScale if running out of computation or export
      }) // NOTE THAT THIS RETURNS A FEATURE COLLECTION, thus we map over the features to add date
        .map(function(feat){
          return feat.set('year', y,'system:time_start', ee.Date.fromYMD(y,1,1).millis());
        });
        // now we return the featurecollection, not the image
      return newFC; 
    })
  ).flatten(); // flatten() the feature collection of feature collections
```

[link code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/3f3cfcfcd8f943dfd0edf2634278c9cf)

Comment: Hi Kuik, thank you for help! Unfortunately, when I replicated the codes, I got the following error: "Image.reduceRegion: Too many pixels in the region. Found 384225549, but maxPixels allows only 10000000. Ensure that you are not aggregating at a higher resolution than you intended; that is a frequent cause of this error. If not, then you may set the 'maxPixels' argument to a limit suitable for your computation; set 'bestEffort' to true to aggregate at whatever scale results in 'maxPixels' total pixels; or both."

Comment: In your "image.reduceRegion()" function, add the 'maxPixels: 384225549'. This ensures that it still calculates.  The number is quite high, so be ready for a timeout...

Comment: Hi Sean, thank you very much for your suggestion! It works when I add the 'maxPixels: 384225549'. Still, the final table only produces average NDVI data aggregated at the country level, while I am looking for data at province level.

Comment: You didn't share the feature collection you are working with, share it to make sure you get appropriate help. If it is a FC, as I suggest it is, apply something like the following: [link](https://code.earthengine.google.com/12c865c6caccf9fdac61b2a3b6609cf0).

Comment: I am using shapefile of Cambodia (ADM 1) available at: https://www.diva-gis.org/gdata. It can also be downloaded from https://code.earthengine.google.com/?asset=users/tronganhtrinh/cambodia_shapefile. However, I got the following error: Error: ImageCollection.fromImages, argument 'images': Invalid type. Expected: List<Image<unknown bands>>. Actual: List<FeatureCollection>. Also, is it possible to extract the monthly NDVI?

Comment: Oops, forget adding a part. Does this work: [link](https://code.earthengine.google.com/3f3cfcfcd8f943dfd0edf2634278c9cf). I guess you didn't set the asset to public, so I cannot open it. Please open a new question for new questions.